# How to show Popup using Dependency Injection in MAUI

Tags: c#, maui

I have a popup from the .NET MAUI Community Toolkit. I have also implemented dependency injection in my application.
I initially was showing the popup by creating an instance of it as follows then dismissing it.

```
LoadingControl loading = new LoadingControl("Downloading your info...");
Shell.Current.ShowPopup(loading);
loading.Close();
```

This was working fine prior to implementing DI in my app. The application started throwing the error that `Cannot access a disposed object` referring to the popup after it has popped-up before on either the same page or elsewhere.
So I figured that I should also dependency inject the popup into the parent view model as below.

**TopicSelectionViewModel.cs**

```
public IApiService ApiService { get; }
        public IDatabaseRepository repository;
        public LoadingControl loadingControl;

        public TopicSelectionViewModel(IApiService apiService, IDatabaseRepository _repo, LoadingControl popup)
        {
            ApiService = apiService;
            repository = _repo;
            loadingControl = popup;
        }
```

I registered the Popup as a transient in `MauiProgram.cs` since I need to use it on different pages.

However, it still throws the error that it cannot access a disposed object after the popup has popped up prior. I thought transient would take care of that. Below is the calling code

**TopicSelectionViewModel.cs**

```
//Shortened for brevity
[RelayCommand]
       async Task Download(Topic topic)
        {
            if (topic is null) return;
            Shell.Current.ShowPopup(loadingControl);

            if (ApiService.InternetAvailable())
            {
                try
                {
                    await repository.SaveTopicAndQuestionsAsync(await ApiService.GetQuestionsAsync(topic.TopicRef), topic.TopicRef);
                }
                catch (Exception ex) 
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                    Debug.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    Refresh();
                    loadingControl.Close();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("No Internet", "Connect to the internet to download", "Ok");
            }
        }
```

Therefore, my question is how do I reuse a popup using Dependency injection in my Maui application?

**EDIT**
I followed one of the comments to encapsulate the popup as a service and then inject the service instead of the popup. However the following error still persists.

```
**System.ObjectDisposedException:** 'Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core.Views.MauiPopup'.'
```

Here is the service I created.
**ILoadingService.cs**

```
public interface ILoadingService
    {
        void ShowLoading();
        void CloseLoading();
    }

    public class LoadingService : ILoadingService
    {
        LoadingPopup Popup;

        public LoadingService()
        {
            Popup = new();
        }

        public void CloseLoading() => Popup.Close();

        public void ShowLoading() => Shell.Current.ShowPopup(Popup);
    }
```

Added the service as a transient.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach of your problem.

Instead of trying to inject disposable objects in your DI, create a service, that is re-using such disposable objects.

(Btw, with the same success you can try to inject every stream you ever going to use in your DI)

Edit: To clarify. Instead of LoadingControl, you have LoadingService.

Edit2: You are constructing your popup once, and you are closing it multiple times. Just like any disposable object, let's say stream for example, you should not be reading it, after it is closed. The same, you should not be displaying popup, after it is closed.

To display what you are doing:

```
stream = new();
stream.read();
stream.close();
stream.read(); // this is throwing exception.
```

Comment: You mean creating an interface, a class the implements the interface and injecting that?

Comment: Yes. Lets say you have interface ILoadingService, that has method that is responsible for managing this LoadingPopup. The Service is injected, not the Disposable object. New popup of that type is being created and disposed when needed. The service may as well be singleton.

Comment: Okay, let me try that.

Comment: @TanakaMawere you keep accessing your objects, that are closed. Once closed it is done. No more use of it. It is disposed. The object is good for nothing. Memory is not usable. The very name "Disposable" should ring a bell.

Comment: Ohhh I thought it worked by recreating the object after it has been disposed in the method. I think I get what you are saying. How should I do it correctly so that the popup appears when I need it

Comment: @TanakaMawere Call constructor > Display > Dispose. Repeat as many times as needed. In the example you are giving, the DisplayLoading should be constructing as well as displaying.